# AWS AppSync with Firebase as OpenID Connect provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, firebase-authentication, openid-connect, aws-appsync

I would like to use firebase auth to secure my AWS AppSync graphql api, as opposed to something like Cognito. There are several reasons behind this like pricing and us already using some other firebase services.

The only viable solution I can see atm is to somehow pass firebase user token to my AppSync graphql api and validate it through OpenID Conneect / OIDC.

I was not able to figure this out nor find any guides on the topic, so wanted to ask here if it is even possible, if so, could any examples be provided or perhaps use-full references?

Here are related fields that need to be provided to AppSync in terms of OpenID connect data https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-appsync.OpenIdConnectConfig.html

Do these exist for firebase auth?

**Update:** I was able to find some documentation on firebase token verification  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library

I believe following URL is what needs to be used as OpenID url setting in AppSync https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com

However AppSync documentation states that they append `/.well-known/openid-configuration` to such url and when I do that to googleapis url above, it throws 404.

Comment: Firebase as OpenID Connect provider - the Issuer is `https://securetoken.google.com/<Firebase projectId>` . That's the URL AppSync wants.

Comment: @identigral awesome! Would you like to provide this as an answer with perhaps more details that might make it useful for others in the future, so I can award you with the bounty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AppSync expects an OpenID Connect Provider (OP). More specifically, it wants the OP's issuer; the rest of metadata is retrieved based on that. From AppSync [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security.html#openid-connect-authorization):

> **OPENID_CONNECT Authorization**
>
> This authorization type enforces OpenID Connect (OIDC) tokens provided by an OIDC-compliant service.
> Your application can leverage users and privileges defined by your
> OIDC provider for controlling access.
>
> An `Issuer` URL is the only required configuration value that you
> provide to AWS AppSync (for example, `https://auth.example.com`). This
> URL must be addressable over HTTPS. AWS AppSync appends
> `/.well-known/openid-configuration` to the issuer URL and locates the
> OpenID configuration at
> `https://auth.example.com/.well-known/openid-configuration` per the
> OpenID Connect Discovery specification

Firebase is (mostly) a middleware. Even though you could have a user account be residing in Firebase, a more typical use case is to plug in some provider such as Google or Microsoft into Firebase. You could then use Firebase APIs to perform various operations without having to know the details of the underlying provider.

Whether acting as middleware or as an identity store with users in Firebase, it's unclear if Firebase is an OIDC-compliant provider. OpenID publishes OIDC conformance tests as well as [entities that have been certified](https://openid.net/certification/). The only Google entity on the latter list is a "Google Federated Identity".  Certification aside, Firebase does issue a signed JWT that [according to them](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin) is morally equivalent to `id_token` in OIDC:

> **ID token verification**
>
> If your Firebase client app communicates with
> your backend server, you might need to identify the currently
> signed-in user on your server so you can perform server-side logic on
> their behalf. You can do this securely by using ID tokens, which are
> created by Firebase when a user signs into an Firebase app.
>
> ID tokens
> conform to the OpenID Connect spec and contain data to identify a
> user, as well as some other profile and authentication related
> information. You can send, verify, and inspect these tokens from your
> own backends. This allows you to securely identify the currently
> signed in user and authorize them into your own backend resources.

If you create a Firebase project, then authenticate via that and examine the issued token, you'll see the `iss` (Issuer) key in the token payload. It has a value of `https://securetoken.google.com/<Firebase projectId>` and that's the URL needed by AppSync.

You can confirm that OIDC metadata is available by concatenating `/.well-known/openid-configuration` with `https://securetoken.google.com/<Firebase projectId>` and doing a GET on the resulting URL. The expected response should look like this:

```
{
  "issuer": "https://securetoken.google.com/<Firebase project id>",
  "jwks_uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com",
  "response_types_supported": [
    "id_token"
  ],
  "subject_types_supported": [
    "public"
  ],
  "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "RS256"
  ]
}
```